# Special compiler flag for unit test runs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have a question concerning visual studios built in test suite.
Is VS studio running these tests with some special compiler flags applied?

The problem description is as following.
I have overloaded the `Equals` function on one of my classes.
During test runs it would be nice, if it could give me some additional information, which members in the class aren't equal at all.

Therefore I'd like to implement some messages only if the application is running in test mode.

Thanks for any reply!
Andreas

Comment: I see this as a really relevant question. In my case I don't want to output a log entry in case of an exception if occurring while unit test is running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VS compiles/builds the projects with the currently selected build configuration. So a solution might be to create a separate build configuration yourself, and then use a constant (e.g. TEST) for the projects in that particular build configuration. The output method execution can then be restricted either with the `#if TEST` directive or with the `[Conditional("TEST")]` attribute. You could configure your build server te allways run the tests with that particual build configuration, so you would see additional output. You would however need to switch between the build configurations manually when running the tests from VS

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I also thought about adding some additional compiler flags, but was not shure if there isn't already one by the test environment.

Answer (score 7):

Create a new solution configuration "Test" (if you don't have it yet) and switch to it. Open project settings, switch to the Build tab and define a new symbol TEST. Press OK.

Change your Equals implementation to

```
public override bool Equals (object obj)
{
    #if TEST
     // Your implementation
    #else
      return base.Equals (obj);
    #endif
}
```

This will compile a different method body for your test configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't realy want to switch between completely different implementations, but just enhance the output a little bit.

Comment: you still can call the base.Equals implementation and provide additional output you need

Answer (score -1):

I have to say I don't like the idea of putting conditional compilation everywhere in your code. It makes it harder to read and debug your code.

Maybe you should take a step back and realize you have two different sets of algorithms for determining if an object is equal. You could factor this code out of the Equals method by using a [Strategy Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Then at runtime you could select the Strategy for the Equals method trough Dependency Injection or maybe a simple function like this in your base class:

```
public override bool Equals (object obj)
{
    if ( EqualsStrategy != null)
    {
        return EqualsStrategy.Equals(this,object);
    }
    else
    {
       return base.Equals(obj);
    }
}
```

In your unit testing you would initialize EqualsStrategy with the function you want to use.

Comment: I see the point and aggree mainly, but I didn't realy want to change the `Equals` implementation. It only should give me some more ouput, so I could find the error causes more easy.

Answer (score -2):

I'd strongly recommend against inserting any *test-only* code in your application. The purpose of a (unit-)test is to test the production quality of the software, not to exercise test-only code.

If your test-only code is working find but the production version is broken your test would be worthless.

Instead, you should write your test in such a way that only one single thing *can* be wrong. That way if the test fails, you already know what's wrong. So, if you are testing an equals method that considers 2 properties, write a set of small tests that verifies what happens in all possible combinations of the two properties and verify the result of the Equals method.

After that you can be confident that the Equals method is correctly implemented and you don't have to test it anywhere else.

Another solution could be to add a test helper that performs additional logging. I like to use extension methods for this. For example:

```
public static class TestExtensions
{
  public static void ShouldEqual( this YourType subject, YourType other )
  {
     // Check parameters for null here if needed
     if( !subject.Equals( other ) )
     {
       // custom logging here
       Assert.Fail("Objects are not equal"); // test fails
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't want to check the `Equals` method by the unit test, but give me some moere hints for searching errors in the 'higher' functions in my code. But I will think about adding a special `AreEqual` implementation for my classes.